# xbap cannot find it's DLLs until I run the file directly

Tags: wpf, iis, deployment, xbap

Lately, when I deploy my xbap, if I browse to the url where IIS hosts it, I see a 'file not found' http error message on some of the DLLs it is trying to download from the Application Files folder.

This will continue to be a problem until I double click the .xbap file in explorer to launch it.  Then I can browse through http:// to the xbap without any problems!

How do I address this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this:

It could be that IIS is not configured to serve *.DLL which is the default behavior. There is a handy feature in the Visual Studio publishing wizard to rename all published files with *.deploy so you only need to register one MIME type with IIS. It's under the Project Properties window->Publish->Options->"Rename all files using the .deploy file extension"